# Tasks: Automatic displaystyle math for items

Tags: tasks

I found in [github](https://github.com/cgnieder/tasks/issues/8), that I can set the item-format of a task list to math mode using `\ensuremath`. This seems to be equivalent to inline math i.e. for writing something like `\task \(x^2 + y^2 = z^2\)`. But what can I do to get the equivalent to

```
\task
\begin{equation*}
x^2 + y^2 = z^2
\end{equation*}
```

I tried to `item-format = \ensuremath\displaystyle`. But this doesn't work.

Here is the MWE from github:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}[2016/05/02]

\settasks{
  item-format = \ensuremath
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(4)
  \task y + 4x
  \task \sin(x)
  \task \int e^x \,dx
  \task a^2 + b^2
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for `item-format` can be a one-argument command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ensuredisplaymath}{m}{\ensuremath{\displaystyle#1}}

\settasks{
  item-format = \ensuredisplaymath
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(4)
  \task y + 4x
  \task \sin(x)
  \task \int e^x \,dx
  \task a^2 + b^2
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]